# uikit 3 - onbeforehide event on uk-switcher li (tab heads)

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, getuikit

I'm using `uikit 3.6.17`, and I'm trying to catch the change event for `ul> li.uk-active`.
According to [docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/tab#events)  there should be some events that are triggered for `uk-switcher` component, but none are fired when the `uk-active`  class is added on `ul > li`.

I have to do some validation before moving to next tab and I want to `preventDefault()` if validation not ok in current  tab. The current result is that tab head is underlining the clicked tab, but tab content is not changed.

According to this [usage docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#programmatic-use) the event should be listened to like this:

```
UIkit.util.on('#offcanvas', 'show', function () {
    // do something
});
```

**My code**

```
<ul uk-tab id="tabHeads">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="uk-switcher uk-margin">
    <li>Lorem </li>
    <li>Ut enim </li>
    <li>Duis aute </li>
</ul>
```

If I do

```
UIkit.util.on('.uk-switcher', 'beforehide', function (ev) {
// this works and stop navigation to next clicked tab
    ev.PreventDefault();
});
```

Now I nedd something tlike this(for stopping clicked tab to be underlined):

```
//this get attached but never triggered
UIkit.util.on('#tabHeads', 'beforehide', function (ev) {
     ev.PreventDefault();
});
```

Am I attaching to the event to the wrong element?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you attaching the event to the wrong element
you need to attach the switch body instead of the tab head

```html
<ul uk-tab>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="uk-switcher uk-margin"  id="tabsBody">
    <li>Lorem </li>
    <li>Ut enim </li>
    <li>Duis aute </li>
</ul>
```

```
UIkit.util.on('#tabsBody', 'beforehide', function (ev) {
     ev.PreventDefault();
});
```